# Protecting a form from being manipulated

Tags: php, forms

Hello my dears you always help me go further.

I have a problem with a form.

How can I protect it from user manipulation after being submitted?

FORM

```
<form method="post" action="/selling.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="{$_SESSION['session_username']}" />
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="$price" />
<input type="hidden" name="nick" value="$nick" />
<input type="hidden" name="class" value="$class" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="$amount" />
<input type="submit" name="reset" class="input_submit" value="Submit" />
</form>";
```

How does it work?

The user logs in on my website, then based on his "$username", I retrieve his info from DB (nickname,class) and based on some conditions I create a "$amount" and "$price" for it.

Everything goes automatically, all the user has to do is to click the "Submit" button.

But I found out that he can manipulate the whole form and change for example the "$price" to 0...

What should I do and how?

Comment: Why do you store amount and price in an editable field then?

Comment: Have you considered using a session to store some of this information vs. storing in hidden fields?  Specifically the user name and price looks suspicious.

Comment: Seems like amount and price shouldn't be submitted by the form, if you dont want users to manipulate them. They should be calculated on the back end?

Comment: This url provides some solutions too to prevent form manipulation:  http://advosys.ca/papers/web/60-form-tampering.html

Comment: Yes, all user input is tainted. You could just add a field to add the items and then calculate the price when you process the form.

Comment: I appreciate every answer, but I must advise you all that I'm noob at PHP, so this was the MAX I could do... I don't know another way to do what I'm trying except by this...I'm wondering an easy way to send those variables to the "selling.php" file...it don't need to be through a form necessairly if it's possible in another way

Comment: Is the price calculated from the database, another php page, or the same php page?  Basically what you want to do is pass the username along every page in the $_SESSION variable, like you are doing, but the calculations are all done on the server so the user would not be able to change the price (Plus you can validate that the price is correct once the order goes through.

Comment: Ajon, the price is calculated on the same page and then sent to "selling.php" by $_POST

Comment: @tjg184 How could I do this on your way? Using session to store the info??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you might derive `$amount` and `$price` from, it seems to be calculated before outputting the form. This means you can also just store those two values in a session like

```
$_SESSION['amount'] = $amount;
$_SESSION['price'] = $price;
```

and get rid of them in the form completely. You will be able to access these sessions in selling.php so long as you start the session before trying to access it by doing:

```
session_start();
```

Through this, none of the sensitive information will be shown in the form/source code, but it will still be available in selling.php.

Remember to always do validations in the backend, i.e. php code, never in the front end.

Comment: I'll test this right now! Maybe take a bit long since I'll need to undo many changes I have done till now, but I'll come to you as soon as possible. Thank you for now

Comment: Ok...I guess I have failed...I did a "$_SESSION['']" for every variable I wanted to be sent to "selling.php", then in the top of the file "selling.php" I putted the "session_start();" thing. But it isn't working...It seems the file, doesn't receive the info.

Comment: You also need a `session_start()` at the very beginning of the file that contains the form. For testing, put `$_SESSION['foo']="bar";` after starting the session in your form file, put `echo $_SESSION['foo']` after starting the session in selling.php, open your form file in the browser, then open selling.php in your browser. It should say "bar" somewhere in your browser window.

Comment: I don't know if it's legal or not, but could I ask you to see my code through some program like Team Viewer?? I ask that because I'm looking for a solution for hours without any success, but I'm plenty sure it's an easy problem...

Comment: NICE! It seems to be working ! More a few tests to ensure it's working perfectly...

Comment: Even if it works, I would like to have your answer regarding my last question (Team Viewer), because I would rather have a professional look into this subject to avoid future issues...

Comment: Post the whole thing on postish (posti.sh) and let me know when done. I will have a look.